# Downsides or cons of using fast_executemany property?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I've started using this `fast_executemany` property when creating a SQLAlchemy engine object for when we load files into SQL Server via pandas. I understand the benefits it has when loading data.

Are there situations when it is *not* recommended to have it enabled for SQL Server tasks? Maybe if only doing singleton inserts all the time? I still don't see how fast_executemany would be slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there situations when it is *not* recommended to have it enabled for SQL Server tasks? Maybe if only doing singleton inserts all the time?

No, `fast_executemany=True` will have no effect on single-row inserts if pyodbc's `.execute()` method is called. One example is [this pandas issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/30884) where the behaviour differs between a DataFrame with a single row (`.execute()`) and multiple rows (`.executemany()`). The fix for that particular issue would be for pandas to always call `.executemany()`, even if the DataFrame only has a single row. (Note also that `fast_executemany=True` does not *cause* the problem, it *fixes* the problem.)

However, there are a couple of other known issues with `fast_executemany=True` and `.to_sql()` in specific cases:

#### 1. Databases with default "supplementary character" (_SC) collations

If the database is defined with a default "…_SC" collation, e.g.,

```py
cnxn.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE {db_name} COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC")
```

then `.to_sql()` will fail for strings longer than 2000 characters.

[pyodbc issue on GitHub](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/835)

#### 2. DataFrames with a lot of NULL-like values

DataFrames that are relatively sparse (contain a lot of NULL-like values like `None`, `NaN`, `NaT`, etc.) can degrade the insert performance of `.executemany()`, although the worst-case would be that `fast_executemany=True` runs about as slowly as `fast_executemany=False`.

[pyodbc issue on GitHub](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/741)

#### 3. Increasing memory consumption with `[n]varchar(max)` columns

`to_sql()` defaults to creating string columns as `varchar(max)` and that can cause memory bloat with `fast_executemany=True`.

[pyodbc issue on GitHub](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/802)

Comment: Thank you! That answers my question completely. When do you plan of fixing these issues? JK :P

Comment: There's a PR for #3 that looks promising. #2 is not really a bug, just a performance issue for which workarounds exist (e.g., using `bcp`). #1 is, IMO, a deficiency in msodbcsql that has yet to be resolved.

Comment: What happens behind the scene with fast_executemany=True? Does it create one insert statements or does it insert in batches?